# Saving a line-break / newline characters into Postgres in nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, newline

I am using pg module in nodejs.

When I read a multi-line string from the DB, it is returned by **pg** module like this:

```
{ "notes":"First line\nSecond line\nThird line\n" }
```

I know that it is properly saved in the database, as using pgAdmin it appears like this:

```
First line 
Second line
Third line
```

If I then try to save this string into the DB, passing it to the driver as:

```
{ "notes":"First line\nSecond line\nThird line\n" }
```

on the next SELECT query I get it back like this:

```
{ "notes":"First line\\nSecond line\\nThird line\\n" }
```

How can I get the driver to interpret the \n characters as it should (i.e. exactly as it returned them to me)?

**EDIT 1 - SELECT code**

```
pool.query('SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = $1', [id], (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error
    }
    response.status(200).json(results.rows)
  })
```

**UPDATE code**

```
const id = parseInt(request.params.id)
let values_array = [
    request.query.notes,
    id
]
pool.query(
`UPDATE products SET notes = $1
WHERE product_id = $2`,
values_array,
(error, results) => {
  if (error) {
    throw error
  }
  response.status(200).send(`User modified with ID: ${id}`)
}
)
```

Comment: Please add the code that does the SELECT and INSERT to the question.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Your SELECT is returning JSON, so the `\n` is escaped. When you actually use the string, perhaps in `console.log(row.notes);` it should be the same as what you stored.